# How actually ECMA-Script 2015 (and above) module loading through import statement works behind the scenes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

Since mostly we're using modules and `import` statement *transpiling* them with tools like *Babel*, I'm intrigued about how native Web browser's implementations will load external files with the so-called `import` statement.

Will modules be loaded using `XmlHttpRequest`/`XmlHttpRequest2` under the hoods?

AFAIK, the whole standard defines a programmatic API as `System` global variable where there're methods like `System.define` to evaluate a JavaScript source code and register it as a named module.

Does this mean that actual module system implementation won't cover external file module loading (meaning that a library/framework or your own vanilla JavaScript code should get the source code using an `XmlHttpRequest`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a **loader standard** being actively developed by the WHATWG that will handle the loading in the browser: http://whatwg.github.io/loader/

As this is still a work in progress, things might still change. As far as I can see, the exact way that the browser loads the files is not specified, but it is [probable that it will use](https://github.com/whatwg/loader/blob/master/roadmap.md) the [`Fetch` API](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) (the Promise-based replacement for XmlHttpRequest2).

In the end, you should be able to use the module syntax with script tags and the browser (or whatever your JS environment is) will handle the loading:

```
<script type="module">
  import x from 'y';
  import a from 'b';

  ...
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="module" src="y.js"></script>
```

Currently, browsers are at different points of implementation:

- **IE/Edge:** Under Consideration
- **Firefox:** In progress
- **Chrome:** In progress
- **Webkit:** Meta Bug

Please feel free to correct me or extend this answer.